# In a Jquery each loop containing elements with different attribute value, why does jquery load event keep firing even with logic to stop it firing

Tags: jquery, foreach

The following code only hits the load logic once per element, but the load event keeps firing previous load calls?

It loads a dynamic url for each unique element.  My results are similar to this

```
Element1
<Br>
Result1
Result1
Result1

Element2
<br>
Result2
Result2

Element3
<br>
Result3

.....
```

If I keep scrolling down the it adds another load call to the previous so

```
Element1   would be...<br>
Result1
Result1
Result1
Result1
```

and so on with each of the other elements

How do I only fire it once per element?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    var shouldBreakLoop = false;
    $("[mediagrid*='mediagrid']").each(function () {
        var mediaGrid = $(this).attr("mediagrid");

        if ($('#' + mediaGrid).length < 1 && is_on_screen($(this))) {

            if ($('#' + mediaGrid).length < 1) {
                $(this).empty();
                $(this).unbind('load').load(mediaGrid.split("--")[1],
                    function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                        if (statusTxt == "success") {
                        }
                    });

                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    id: mediaGrid,
                    name: mediaGrid
                }).appendTo('form');

                shouldBreakLoop = true;
            }

        } else {

        }

        if (shouldBreakLoop) {
            return false;
        }
    });

});

function is_on_screen(elem) {

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = elem.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + elem.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + elem.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};
```

Comment: `unbind('load')` has nothing to do with the ajax use of `load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the items that were already picked by ajax.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    $("[mediagrid*='mediagrid']").each(function () {
        var mediaGrid = $(this).attr("mediagrid");

        if ($('#' + mediaGrid).length < 1 && is_on_screen($(this)) && !$(this).hasClass('parsed')) {

                $(this).addClass('parsed');

                $(this).load(mediaGrid.split("--")[1],
                    function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                        if (statusTxt == "success") {
                        }
                    });

                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    id: mediaGrid,
                    name: mediaGrid
                }).appendTo('form');


        }
    });

});
```